# Getting the actual height of a UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a NSAttributedString being passed into a UITextView:

```
NSAttributedString *str = @"A really long string ... that continues for awhile";
```

The string is random in length and I want to pass it into a UITextView.

```
myTextView.attributedText = str;
```

I need the width of the UITextView to be 300 but how do I find the heigt?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken you can do this:

```
[myTextView sizeToFit];
```

And then retrieve the height from `myTextView.bounds.size.height`. Note though that `UITextView`s also add some padding to the edges so you may want to subtract that from the height.

If I am mistaken than here is an alternative that is less clean but will work:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300.f, yourMaxHeight)];
label.attributedText = myTextView.attributedText;
label.numberOfLines = INFINITY;
[label sizeToFit];

CGFloat height = label.bounds.size.height;
```

This of course does not include the `UITextView` padding.

Comment: Also, `sizeToFit` is implemented for all `UIControl`s (including `UIButton`, `UIImageView`). It automatically adjusts the frame (excl. the origin) to its contents.

Comment: what is yourMaxHeight

Comment: actually I have the UILabel code working but want a UITextView without the padding

Comment: It's a `CGFloat` you can define (e.g. `100.f`). Have you tried `[myTextView sizeToFit]`? I think it should work.

Comment: If you want only to get size, call `CGSize texViewSize = [myTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX)]`.
This gives you height without actually resizing textview.